# remove items from object if value is empty

Tags: javascript

So I'm taking a form and using `serializeArray()` to get all the forms data. There are 10 text inputs. What I am trying to do is skip the forms that return a empty result or forms that have "" as value. Here is what I came up with and it returns the index of the forms with "" or empty results correctly.

```
$("#" + forms).on("submit", function(event) {
    var allData = $(this).serializeArray();

    event.preventDefault();
    for (var key in allData) {
        if (allData[key].value === "") {
                    allData.splice(key, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

But when I add `allData.splice(key, 1);` it doesn't remove all the values with "" as a result. I basically want to remove any input that isn't going to have a value.

Also the structure of the objec is as follows.

```
[0]
  name: "emailone",
  value "some@email.com"
[1]
  name: "passwordone",
  value: "123asd"
[2]
  name: "emailtwo",
  value "another@email.com"
[3]
  name: "passwordtwo",
  value: "asd123"
[4]
  name: "emailthree",
  value ""
[5]
  name: "passwordthree",
  value: ""
```

Comment: It works in my tests... what result do you get ?

Comment: it only remove some of the elements not all

Comment: `delete` seems to work well as Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy provided below.  my solution only remove some of the elements not all with ""

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you are altering the array while traversing it...

When you `key` is 4 and the value is '' you remove that element (*succesfully*) but when you splice the array it becomes a smaller one.. so the element at position 5 is now at 4. Your `key` variable is increased to 5 but now there is no element 5 in your array..

You need to traverse it backwards

```
$("#" + forms).on("submit", function(event) {
    var allData = $(this).serializeArray();

    event.preventDefault();
    for (var key = allData.length-1; key >= 0 ; key--) {
        if (allData[key].value === "") {
                    allData.splice(key, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By splicing an array as you iterate over it, you can accidentally skip values - in this case, by removing a value at index four, you decrease the index of the following value by one. The loop than increments to five, and the value that started at the fifth index is skipped.

A few other answers have posted reasonable ways to work around this. If you're working with a newer version of JavaScript or with a library like jQuery or underscore, you could alternatively do this:

```
allData = allData.filter(function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";
});
```

With jQuery, this can be written as

```
allData = $.grep(allData, function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";
});
```

and in underscore:

```
allData = _.filter(allData, function(e) {
  return e.value !== "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to achieve your need,

```
for (var key in allData) {
        if (allData[key].value === "") {
             delete allData[key]; 
        }
    }
```

<s>additionally you don't need explicitly get the value by this `toallData[key].value`, `toallData[key]` will simply return the value associated with the particular key.</s>

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RzKf7/)

---

### Updated:

```
    for (var i=0; i < allData.length ; I++) {
        if (allData[i].value === "") {
               allData.splice(i, 1);
               i--;
        }
    }
```

You should `decrement` the value of the `index` by one, every time you are removing an object from the array.

Comment: nice! how about a jquery solution also?

Comment: how would i do this in jquery

Comment: While this is valid javascript (which will definitely work with Jquery) it doesn't solve the problem the way Mr. 10 wants it to. In the question, it looks like he is iterating over an array, and is matching against items in the array that a have a field with the name "value" that is equal to "". Your example works with keys in an object. Delete won't remove items from an array, only set them to undefined. Even if it did, this answer would still run into the problem of skipping elements as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 As usual, I feel the need to grit my teeth and declare with ire that JQuery is not a language. It is a library for a highly extensible language. That language that you are using is **JavaScript**.

Comment: @TwentyMiles `this answer would still run into the problem of skipping elements as mentioned in other answers.` Of course not, delete will simply make that particular object null, it wont completely remove that cell from the array as slice do. So that the index mismatching problem will not occur. Anyway I just provided another solution, a traditional one. :) I think OP is actually after this kind of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrLength = allData.length, i, cleanArray = [], serializedArr;

for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i += 1{
  if(allData[i] != ""){
    cleanArray.push(allData[i]);
  }
}

serializedArr = cleanArray.serializeArray();
```